# Making Vista / 7 User Frame control? (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, controls, themes

I notice Vista/7 uses this type of control as well as Windows Live Messenger. This is the control: [image]

[image]
[image]

How can this control be programably added to a WinAPI application?

Thanks

Comment: That is what I call a bounty! :) Hopefully someone will figure out a way now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This resource is Bitmap 7016 in explorer.exe's resources. It is a 32 bit bitmap, so it has an extra alpha channel. This is how it is done.

Comment: Very good job! But a few relevant questions: Is this an undocumented feature? Would it be copyright violation to add the bitmap to one's own application?

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand I'm not sure but I've uploaded the native one if you want to see it.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost what you want (but surprisingly far from it):

```
t := OpenThemeData(Handle, 'STARTPANEL');
DrawThemeBackground(t, Canvas.Handle, SPP_USERPICTURE, 0, rect(10, 10, 100, 100), nil);
```

(Delphi code, but only WinAPI functions.)

Maybe some other part suits you better: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773210(VS.85).aspx